# Search bar looks weird if width is less than 116

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to create square search bar but when I set width less than 116, search icon and textfield area moved out of search bar. Please refer first search bar of screenshot.

[image: SearchBar]

Comment: So don’t do that.

Comment: @matt, I need square search bar with search icon. It will expand on click

Comment: Well as you’ve discovered that’s not supported. You need to rethink what your interface will be.

Comment: Make a custom!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by adding following code to set constraints manually for `searchTextField`.

```
searchBar.searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
searchBar.searchTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBar.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
searchBar.searchTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBar.rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
searchBar.searchTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBar.topAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
searchBar.searchTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBar.bottomAnchor, constant: -6).isActive = true
```

[image]

While expanding width, I marked `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` as true.

```
searchBar.searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

[image]